# How to stretch a form into a horizontal div by using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Assume that we have a standard form with input and button elements, as in the following example. How can we stretch this form horizontally and **responsively**  by using CSS Flexbox?

```html
<div>
    <form class="sampleform" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input
            type="text"
            class="input-text"
            name="sampleinput"
            placeholder="A placeholder ..."
        />
        <button
            type="submit"
            class="button"
        >➕
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```css
form {
  display: flex;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <form class="sampleform" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
       <input
            type="text"
            class="input-text"
            name="sampleinput"
            placeholder="A placeholder ..."
        />
        <button
             type="submit"
             class="button"
         >➕
         </button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what to say.. It works on the snipet and on jsfiddle.
Could you try to reproduce the bug for me ?

Comment: Let me try to clarify a bit more; I want to have a one-line form that spreads along the width of mobile screen. The input field is going to take the most width and the "+" icon will be positioned on the far right, on the mobile screen.

Comment: I must be dumb but I really think this is what I did.

Comment: @GokhanKaradag how this code is not accomplishing your expected behaviour?

Comment: @GokhanKaradag I think is not clear what do you need. Try to reproduce the error you have, and then tell clearly whats ur exected result and update your question.

Comment: @Sandwell As you said, your solution works on jsfiddle. I don't understand why it doesn't work on my env. I am trying the understand now ..

Comment: I nested input's CSS within form's CSS in my SCSS file and it wasn't working. Now it is OK.